# c# cannot convert type chromium3.Loginuser to "bool"

Tags: c#, mysql

Hello im creating simple login.When button1 is clicked it should verify it  but if i do `bool r = validate_login(user, pass);` and `if (r)` on that button click i get " Cannot implicitly convert type 'chromium3.LoginUser' to 'bool' " 
Any advice would be welcome. Thanks!

I have tryied:changing bool to LoginUser.

```cs
private LoginUser validate_login(string user, string pass)
        {
            db_connection();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from table2 where username=@user and password=@pass and UserID=@UserID";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);


            cmd.Connection = connect;
            LoginUser usr = new LoginUser();
            MySqlDataReader login = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (login.Read())
            {

                usr.UserID = login["UserID"].ToString();
                usr.valid = true;
            }
            return usr;
        }



        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                string user = usertype.Text;
                string pass = password.Text;


                if (user == "" || pass == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Empty Fields Detected ! Please fill up all the fields");
                    return;
                }
                bool r = validate_login(user, pass); //problem line
                if (r)
                {
                    LoginUser usr = new LoginUser();
                    usr = validate_login(user, pass);
                    if (usr.valid)
                    {
                        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", usr.UserID));
                        UserDetails.m_gnUserId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["UserID"]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

It should verify credentials as normal and save usersID to UserDetails class.

Comment: validate_login returns a LoginUser instance, not a boolean. Besides, why are you calling validate_login two times consecutively ?

Comment: Just a mistake forgot to remove it. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question, but shouldn't be something like this https://pastebin.com/DUddxkFq, just remove the bool and if (r) part.

Comment: Never, ever store passwords as plaintext - salt and hash them.  `AddWithValue` is generally held to be a bad idea too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what I understand this code can solve your problem

```
private LoginUser validate_login(string user, string pass)
{
    db_connection();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "Select * from table2 where username=@user and password=@pass and UserID=@UserID";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", user);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);


    cmd.Connection = connect;
    LoginUser usr = null;
    MySqlDataReader login = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (login.Read())
    {
        usr = new LoginUser();
        usr.UserID = login["UserID"].ToString();
        usr.valid = true;
    }
    return usr;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        string user = usertype.Text;
        string pass = password.Text;


        if (user == "" || pass == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Empty Fields Detected ! Please fill up all the fields");
            return;
        }
        var r = validate_login(user, pass); //problem line
        if (r != null)
        {
            if (r.valid)
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}", r.UserID));
                UserDetails.m_gnUserId = Convert.ToInt32(reader["UserID"]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```